# How to remove package from apt-get autoremove "queue"

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

I just installed Calibre for ebook management via apt-get on Ubuntu 10.04, however I found out that it's one major version behind the current release, so I decided to reinstall it directly from sources.

When I uninstalled the packaged version, apt added bunch of dependencies to the autoremove queue, and as I installed newer version of Calibre from sources, it has no knowledge of it being dependent on those packages.

Now I basically have all libraries that I want, but they are still in the autoremove queue.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqt4-script libqt4-designer libqt4-dbus python-lxml python-cherrypy3
  python-encutils libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt4-help python-qt4 python-clientform
  python-sip python-django python-mechanize libqt4-svg python-django-tagging
  libphonon4 libqt4-xml libqt4-assistant libqt4-webkit libqt4-scripttools
  python-beautifulsoup python-pypdf python-dateutil python-cssutils
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

**How do I tell apt that I want to keep these packages installed, without reinstalling them manually?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use apt-get install:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-script libqt4-designer libqt4-dbus python-lxml python-cherrypy3 python-encutils libqt4-xmlpatterns libqt4-help python-qt4 python-clientform python-sip python-django python-mechanize libqt4-svg python-django-tagging   libphonon4 libqt4-xml libqt4-assistant libqt4-webkit libqt4-scripttools  python-beautifulsoup python-pypdf python-dateutil python-cssutils
```

It won't actually install them. It will just set the flag to manually installed.

Answer (score 3):

Apt-get knows the packages were installed automatically as dependencies. You should mark them as 'manual' to let apt-get know you want them to remain installed:

```
apt-mark manual [packages]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, you wan to mark these packages to appear as if they were installed manually. `Apt-get` does not allow you to do this. However, `aptitude` allows the manipulation of these flags.

Have a look at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-really-better-than-apt-get). Some people discourage the mix of using `apt-get` and `aptitude`. So, be careful!